# Chrome and Firefox processing JavaScript/HTML differently

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, multiple-browsers

Ok, so the weirdest thing happened here.
I have a php file with Javascript to write onto elements based on events on the webpage.
And there are 3 html forms on the page. One is a searchbox, one has all inputs hidden and gets submitted on a certain event, and one is a textbox and a button on clicking which the javascript writes the text to a certain  element in the page.
Also, this third form is itself written onto the document by the javascript on clicking another button.
The problem is, while doing certain operations with this third form, i need to reference one of its inputs values (newSkillName).

So for this third form, In Chrome-

> document.forms[1].newSkillName.value

works,
while in Firefox-

> document.forms[2].newSkillName.value

works.

I, however, managed to fix the code. But i'm still curious. Why did Chrome and Firefox process the abnormality differently?? Any idea?

Comment: Without seeing the code this is only a guess: _If_  you have this dynamically created `form` nested within another `form`, browsers may treat them in a different way. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) says: "`[form] Permitted content: Flow content, but with no contained <form> elements.`".

Comment: Or, another blind guess, are all the forms error-free? Maybe one browser totally ignores forms with missing `action` attributes or something like that.

Comment: Just made a quick test with nested `form`s. FF22, Chrome27 and IE10 all return `1` from `document.forms.length`, though there were two `form`s in the HTML code. Can you provide a link to the page or save an example at http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: ok guys, i fixed the error in my code somehow...but i'm still curious. Why did Firefox and Chrome process it differently?? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the form elements unique ID attributes and reference them with document.getElementById(id).

You could also use the NAME attribute and reference the form by name document.forms["name_of_form"];

Comment: so you're saying,
if i have a form like : <form id="formId" name="formName" method="get"><input type="text" name="newSkill"></form>

I call it as 

document.forms["formName"].newSkill.value

?

Comment: And I can also use document.getElementById("inputId").value

? where <input id="inputId" type="text" name="newSkill">

Comment: @GothamCityRises - yes that is what I'm saying. You can reference the inputs or form directly by ID with getElementById.

Answer (score 0):

The quick workaround/copout fix is to hunt down the field in the DOM a diffferent way.  For example, with id='NewSkillName' use `document.getElementById('NewSkillName').value`.